# C# Selenium WebDriver - How to use proxy with Authentication?

Tags: c#, authentication, selenium-webdriver, proxy, geckodriver

The program gives an error when I run it with authentication.

```
        var options = new FirefoxOptions();

        string proxyInfo = "user:password@host:port";
        var proxy = new Proxy
        {
            HttpProxy = proxyInfo,
            SslProxy = proxyInfo,
            FtpProxy = proxyInfo,
        };
        options.Proxy = proxy;

        var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.FirefoxBinaryPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";

        WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
```

Screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gsy3.png)

The program works when I run it without authentication. It only asks for authentication when the website is opened.

```
        var options = new FirefoxOptions();

        string proxyInfo = "host:port";
        var proxy = new Proxy
        {
            HttpProxy = proxyInfo,
            SslProxy = proxyInfo,
            FtpProxy = proxyInfo,
        };
        options.Proxy = proxy;

        var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.FirefoxBinaryPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";

        WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
```

Screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOHXi.png)

How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: I tried it for Chrome, it's the same, add user:pass, there is a problem. Please help. Is there a solution for mozilla or chrome?

Comment: Tell me a solution. If necessary, you can connect to my computer and check. But please help.

Comment: ++++++++++++++++